# Route not updating of mean stack application

Tags: angularjs, mean

I have hosted my mean stack application on Amazon AWS & Buy domain from godaddy. I have succesfully deployed my application to AWS using bitnami and its working on my domain.

But when I access any link, page is changed but route/url not changing.

I have used angular js $locationprovider as

```
 $locationProvider.hashprefix("!");
```

Also, when I hover on the links, links are appearing correct but url is not changing on click.

Please, if any anybody have a solution, let me know.

Comment: do you get any errors in the browsers console?

Comment: No, i didn't get any error

Comment: then provide more code, it's hard to debug smth by guessing

Comment: Thanks for your time, it's fixed now.